# How to install R-base sid in Debian jessie?

Tags: debian, software-installation, r

I want to install `R-base` sid [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/r-base) in Debian. 
It would be great if some CRAN packages installed can be maintained in the SID version. 
Code

```
sudo apt install r-base/unstable
```

Output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Release 'unstable' for 'r-base' was not found
```

I also tried unsuccessfully `sudo apt-get install r-base/unstable`. I cannot find R 3.4.x in `apt search R-base| grep 3.4`. 
I think it can be enough to add the source of the R-base sid in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. 
However, I could not find the exact address in the package homepage.

OS: Debian 8.7
R: current 3.3.3

Comment: Create an apt preference file https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences , I don't know if installing R from Sid will break something or not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [official instructions on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/) and make the appropriate changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Then, to install the backported R 3.4 packages, you can do

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install r-base
```

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `-t jessie-cran34` instead of `jessie-backports`? (I haven’t tried it, I’m just going by the release information in the CRAN Release file.)

Comment: @StephenKitt The above works. I do not know what is the difference to `cran34`.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error with the official instructions, the following worked for me:

Use a text editor to add the following to `etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main
```

(careful, here we're add support for *more* than just R).

You can also do everything from the command line with e.g.

```
d0="[trusted=yes] http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main"
d1="deb $d0"
d2="deb-src $d0"
sudo (echo "$d1"; echo "$d2") >> /etc/apt/sources.list
## check this worked 
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then

```
### ensure have keyring
sudo apt-get install -y debian-archive-keyring
## add key for R (I think this is still necessary)
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
### ensure no errors with apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libappstream4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev libopenblas-base
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Why are you doing `var=$(echo string)`?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way; I'm using `echo` to join strings together...

Comment: Yes, there’s a better way: `d0="[trusted=yes] http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main"`, `d1="deb $d0"`, and `d2="deb-src $d0"`.

Comment: Also, while I suppose there’s nothing really *wrong* with the `cat`, most people would do `(echo "$d1"; echo "$d2") >> /etc/apt/sources.list`.  (or `(echo "$d1"; echo "$d2") | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`, if you’re not already root.)